# Backbone.js - How do I save a collection to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I have included [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) in my code but I can't seem to find a way to save my collection (or more specifically an attribute of my collection) to localStorage.

This is my code for the collection:

```
//Collection
var Playlist = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Song,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('playlist'),
    initialize: function(models,options) {
        _.extend(this,_.pick(options, 'currentTrack'));
    },
    url: 'metadata',
    parse: function(response){
        return response
    },
    save: function(){
        Backbone.sync('create', this, {
            succes: function() {
                console.log('Saved');
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('There was an error');
            }
        });
    },
    currentTrack: 0,
    currentTime: 0
});
```

Before I added the `save` method there wasn't any (as I read in the Backbone docs). I added that method according to [this post](http://c2journal.com/2013/03/23/backbone-js-save-collections/)

So, how should I do this?

Comment: which attribute do you want to save?

Comment: The last two: currentTrack and currentTime

Answer (score 2):

Backbone collection is for simply storing models, and the models contain data. So I don't think localStorage plugin has a built in way to store custom attributes on a collection.

Your attributes are for keeping the state of application, which should be part of "controller" which in backbone's case is the "view". And view can directly set/get this from localStorage.

As simple as:

```
saveState: function(){
  localStorage.setItem('playlist.state',JSON.stringify({
    currentTrack: this.currentTrack,
    currentTime: this.currentTime
  }));
},
retrieveState: function(){
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playlist.state'));
}
```

You can do the same inside the collection if you want. There is no reason to hack into backbone.localStorage plugin via backbone sync to do this.

Comment: I would have simply put that data inside of a model.

Comment: @EmileBergeron You mean a different model just for holding state, right?

Comment: Yes exactly! Since OP is using localStorage and it's already made to sync model attributes, why not have the features of a model in addition to avoid manually using the localStorage.